# Using GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT glMapBufferRange for the entire buffer and it's safety

Tags: opengl

I want to write into a texture buffer at arbitrary positions without doing a large data upload to increase my performance. I don't do glSubBufferData since there are a lot of non-contiguous writes which causes significant performance loss for AMD GPUs.

Uploading all the new data is also costly. Writing only what changed significantly improves performance.

To achieve this, I used GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT which *doubles* my performance, but am worried I am hitting undefined behavior despite the massive performance boost I am seeing (and everything is rendered correctly).

My intention in the following pseudocode is to write into a texture buffer, which is used in a vertex shader.

```
void render()
{
    if (frameNumber % 50 == 0) {
        ptr = glMapBufferRange(..., GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
        randomlyWriteIntoBuffer(ptr);
        glUnmapBuffer(...);
    }
    
    // do everything else (upload, bind VAO, texture, program, etc)
    bindTextureBufferThatWasMappedAbove();
    glDrawArrays(...);
    
    frameNumber++;
}
```

My code has the following constraints:

- I only write into the mapped texture buffer either once at the beginning of the frame, or never write for that frame.
- I only read from the buffer it in the shader via the texture buffer.
- I do *not* care if data gets partially stomped on while a draw call is happening. It is acceptable if there is a mixture of stale and non-stale data when a draw call happens, like half of the buffer has the latest mapping data written, and the other half is old, provided that old data either eventually is visible with the newer data at some later frame or some subsequent buffer writes overwrite it.
- The backing buffer I am writing into is not used anywhere else.

My users do not all have GL 4.4+ so I cannot use persistent flags.

If this is undefined behavior, how could I achieve uploads?

Comment: "*I do not care if data gets stomped in the process.*" This doesn't make sense. If you don't care if the uploaded data is actually correct, then why upload anything at all?

Comment: @NicolBolas Why are you assuming it is not correct? I will edit that point to clarify. Briefly, the end users do not care if the data is recent and stale, such as a buffer maybe receiving only half of the newly written data when the draw call is happening instead of all the data being written and visible to the shader. The end users deem it unacceptable if the entire write is neither ever visible or it is not overwritten by some later frame's write. The question is what practical consequences arise from using this bit and going straight to a draw call as seen in the pseudocode?

Comment: "*the end users do not care if the data is recent and stale*" Um... why not? That data means something, right? It affects the rendered output, right? If half the data is from the previous frame and half from the current frame, then the result you get will be fractured. That's what I don't understand; what are you doing where incorrect rendering is deemed OK?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes it is deemed okay by the customers to sacrifice some correctness for performance. I am not making the rules unfortunately.

Comment: How much is "some"? Undefined behavior is *undefined*; you have no idea what it could do.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is pretty clear on the behavior of unsynchronized mapping. Specifically, by doing it, *you* are responsible for synchronization:

> No GL error is generated if pending operations which source or modify the buffer overlap the mapped region, but the result of such previous and any subsequent operations is undefined.

"Undefined" means *undefined*; there are no guarantees about anything. If you do not have the CPU wait to map the buffer until previous operations that read from it have completed, then OpenGL offers zero guarantees about what happens next.